# passing NSInteger to a method does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am calling a method getAllProductsByManufacturedID which receives NSInteger as a parameter, see code below:

```
// call the method with int value
[dbAccess getAllProductsByManufacturedID:5];

// method for extract all row with manufactured id = ?
- (NSMutableArray*)getAllProductsByManufacturedID:(NSInteger *)manufactID
{
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE manufacturerid = ?";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK) 
    {
       sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, manufactID);
    }
}
```

I think there are two problems:
1) (NSMutableArray*)getAllProductsByManufacturedID:(NSInteger *)manufactID
2) sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, manufactID);

Answer (score 5):

`NSInteger` is not an object. You generally do not take a pointer to it. Your signtuare here should be:

```
- (NSArray*)allProductsForManufacturedID:(NSInteger)manufactID
```

Using `get` suggests that `manufactID` is a return-by-refrence, which it isn't. You also want to use `xForY` here rather than `xByY`. Your name sounds like it should return an `NSDictionary`.

You can return this as a mutable array if that's particularly good for your caller, but generally this would be a normal array. That way if you later change this code to cache the result, callers won't be surprised.